# Instantiate specific class object depending on $variable value without using conditions

Tags: php, class, object, conditional-statements, switch-statement

I would want to write the following code without switch, if else or the ternary operator. The code is shown below:

```
  switch (type){
  case 'bed':
     function create{
      return new Bed($customer, $price, $dimensions );
     }
      break;
  case 'desk':
     function create{
      return new Desk($customer, $price, $dimensions);
    }
      break;
  
  case 'chair':
       function create{
      return new Chair($customer, $price, $dimensions, $type );
   }
      break;

  }
```

Comment: To what end do you want to rewrite this? And why such arbitrary and frankly bewildering requirements?

Comment: Why would you define functions inside a case statement

Comment: Sounds like the requirements of a class or interview where they want to see you implement interfaces.

Comment: I reckon this question needs more focus and we don't yet have a [mcve] by which we can deem answers good/bad or right/wrong.   My gut tells me that [this wil put you on the right path](https://dinocajic.blogspot.com/2015/08/php-polymorphism.html?m=1).

Answer (score 0):

You can make the code more concise by returning a new instance of the class by using class name stored in `$type`. For calling the constructor with different parameters, make use of splat operator by collecting the params in an array.

```
<?php

function create($type){
    global $customer, $price, $dimensions;
    $className = ucfirst($type);
    $params = [$customer, $price, $dimensions, $type];
    return new $className(...$params);
}

create($type);
```

Comment: You should not use `global` in PHP.

Comment: @fabpico Thanks I didn't know. Should we burninate the wordpress tag here on Stackoverflow?

Comment: @nice you can go without the condition.  You can safely pass too many parameters to a function/method. https://3v4l.org/QORYF

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for notifying.  Updated my answer. Didn't know PHP had this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call another class here, you can set the classes you want to global. Then in the functions below, you can call them from there using global.

Example output:
[image: output photo]

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  class Bed{
    function __construct($customer, $price, $dimensions){
      echo "Ordered <b>Bed</b> for: <b>$customer</b> at the price of: <b>$price</b> and with the dimensions of: <b>$dimensions</b>";
    }
  }
  class Chair{
    function __construct($customer, $price, $dimensions){
      echo "Ordered <b>Chair</b> for: <b>$customer</b> at the price of: <b>$price</b> and with the dimensions of: <b>$dimensions</b>";
    }
  }
  class Desk{
    function __construct($customer, $price, $dimensions){
      echo "Ordered <b>Desk</b> for: <b>$customer</b> at the price of: <b>$price</b> and with the dimensions of: <b>$dimensions</b>";
    }
  }

  class Furniture{

    private function bed($customer, $price, $dimensions){
      new Bed($customer, $price , $dimensions);
    }

    private function chair($customer, $price, $dimensions){
      new Chair($customer, $price , $dimensions);
    }

    private function desk($customer, $price, $dimensions){
      new Desk($tcustomer, $price , $dimensions);
    }

    function __construct($type = null, $customer = null, $price = null, $dimensions = null) {
      return $this->$type($customer, $price, $dimensions);
    }
  }

  new Furniture('bed','Joes Momma','$1.99','4x5x2');
```

Comment: You should not write HTML with PHP.

Comment: That's a strange critique @fab.  I use PHP to generate HTML all the time.  Perhaps you mean to say that HTML markup should only be generated in the View.  That's good advice, but for the sake of Joes's answer I think ot is completely forgivable to demonstrate the output with some simple HTML.

Comment: @mickmackusa Frontend and backend should be split so that you can hire people which are specialized. HTML is frontend. PHP is backend.

Comment: I understand your purist stance.

Comment: @fabpico -> Are you going to tell that to Wordpress?

Comment: @fabpico so templating frameworks like [Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade) are wrong? MVC might not be as popular as it once was but it's still very widely used. SSR is another pattern in which markup is generated server-side. Blanket statements like yours are more limiting than you might think

Comment: @Phil -> Nice job on your suggestion with the Factory Function.

Comment: @JoesMomma If wordpress requires to write html in php echos, then why does it not do like symfony with separate template files? Then you have twig files where the html are stored, and php which controllers only responds response objects with eg. array primitives.

Comment: @Phil I am not saying templating frameworks are wrong. I am saying writing html code in php files is bad.

Comment: @Phil, I just started using Laravel with blade. and that seems to been the standard. I think I am going to utilize the concepts of Laravel but build my own so I can have the API function without exposing what framework. Or maybe I am missing something because it exposes if the route or method is not there. I have even used fallbacks.

Answer (score 0):

*- Looks like you're trying to write a factory function.*

Instead of using a conditional, you can create a list of allowed *types* mapping to class creator functions.

```php
enum FurnitureType: string {
    case Bed = 'bed';
    case Desk = 'desk';
    case Chair = 'chair';
}

class FurnitureFactory {
    private $creators;
    
    public function __construct() {
        // ideally this would be static but PHP no-likey
        $this->creators = [
            FurnitureType::Bed->value => static fn($customer, $price, $dimensions) =>
                new Bed($customer, $price, $dimensions),
            FurnitureType::Desk->value => static fn($customer, $price, $dimensions) =>
                new Desk($customer, $price, $dimensions),
            FurnitureType::Chair->value => static fn($customer, $price, $dimensions) =>
                new Chair($customer, $price, $dimensions, FurnitureType::Chair->value),
        ];
    }

    public function creator(FurnitureType $type, $customer, $price, $dimensions) {
        $creator = $this->creators[$type->value] ??
            throw new Exception("Not implemented for type {$type->name}");
        return fn() => $creator($customer, $price, $dimensions);
    }
}

$factory = new FurnitureFactory();
$bedCreator = $factory->creator(FurnitureType::Bed, 'customer', 100, '200x100');
print_r($bedCreator());

$chairCreator = $factory->creator(FurnitureType::Chair, 'customer', '50', '20x50');
print_r($chairCreator());
```

<sub>Requires PHP 8.1.0 or later</sub>

https://3v4l.org/fDuKG#v8.1.12

Answer (score -1):

you can use the same code in if else statement like below .
if == do not work try to add === instead

```
if(type == "bed"){

     function create{
      return new Bed($customer, $price, $dimensions );
     }}
else if(type == "desk"){

     function create{
      return new Desk($customer, $price, $dimensions);
    }}
    else if(type == "chair"){

       function create{
      return new Chair($customer, $price, $dimensions, $type );
   }
  }
```

Comment: One of OPs requirements is "_without switch, if else or the ternary operator_"